# Make mypy recognize asserting type of list

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have code like this

```py
from typing import Union, List

class Player:
    number: str

def func(things: List[Union[Player, str]]):
    if isinstance(things[0], Player):
        print(" ".join(p.number for p in things))
    else:
        print(" ".join(things))
```

Mypy highlights the `p.number` and the `things` in the else block gives me this error:

```
[mypy error] [E] Item "str" of "Union[Player, str]" has no attribute "number"
```

I have also tried

```py
def func2(things: List[Union[Player, str]]):
    if all(isinstance(thing, Player) for thing in things):
        print(" ".join(p.number for p in things))
    elif all(isinstance(thing, str) for thing in things):
        print(" ".join(things))
```

But I get the same error. How do I get mypy to recognize that I'm asserting that every element of a list is a specific type?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to have a "list of (players or strings)", you want "(a list of players) or (a list of strings)":

```
def func(things: Union[List[Player], List[str]]):
    if isinstance(things[0], Player):
        things = cast(List[Player], things)
        print(" ".join(p.number for p in things))
    else:
        things = cast(List[str], things)
        print(" ".join(things))
```

I don't think there's a more graceful way to get the typechecking to work than the `cast`, though; mypy doesn't seem to be quite clever enough to infer the type of `things` based on your `things[0]` check alone, and you can't do `isinstance(things, List[Player])`.